# Changing in topology after ST_DUMP?

Tags: postgis, topology

I would like to know why I see a sort of change in topology after having used ST_Dump.

First, I have done buffers on a table made of polygons. 
Second, I have made the difference between my buffers and polygons to get ring
Third, I have done the following test :

```
SELECT
t1.geom,
t1.idu
FROM ring t1
INNER JOIN polygon t2
ON ST_TOUCHES(t1.geom, t2.geom)
WHERE ST_TOUCHES(t1.geom, t2.geom) IS TRUE AND t1.idu = t2.idu
```

And the result is correct

Then, I have split my rings with lines after having added the ST_SplitPolygon function (because when I try to use ST_Split it doesn't work although I use Postgis 2.3) :

```
CREATE TABLE ring_split
AS SELECT geom(ST_Dump(ST_SplitPolygon(t1.geom, t2.geom))) as geom,
t1.idu,
t1.id_ilot
FROM ring t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT idu, ST_UNION(geom) as geom
FROM lines
GROUP BY idu) as t2
ON t1.idu = t2.idu
WHERE t1.idu = t2.idu
```

And when I lauch the same test :

```
SELECT
t1.geom,
t1.idu
FROM ring_split t1
INNER JOIN polygon t2
ON ST_TOUCHES(t1.geom, t2.geom)
WHERE ST_TOUCHES(t1.geom, t2.geom) IS TRUE AND t1.idu = t2.idu
```

The result is not correct.

On the left, the result of the first test, on the right, the result of the second test

[image: On the left, the result of the first test, on the right, the result of the second test]

May somebody help me to understand why the result is not the same and how to get all ring_split with the ST_Touches query but without using a buffer ?

Comment: sidenote: if you do a _JOIN ... ON <exression>_, don´t also declare that _<expression>_ in the _WHERE_ clause; that is unnecessarily redundant, effectively doing the same thing twice.

Comment: okay, after giving my sidenote a second thought, I am not sure if it indeed does the same thing twice, but much rather be the actual problem here (note: in any case, don´t do it without an unlikely reason to). Try your queries without the repeating _<expression>_ in your _WHERE_ clause. Alternatively, you could also try _... ST_Touches(St_Snap(t1.geom, t2.geom, <low_tolerance>), t2.geom) ..._ in your test query, where _<low_tolerance>_ is given in your used SRID units and should be in the range of a few meters only. Use that to verify that those missing polygons exist.

Comment: With a 0.0000005 meters tolerance I get more results than with a 1 meter tolerance but I still don't get all the rings I wish. In my query, I think it is finally not necessary to use the Where clause because the number of rows is the same... but it doesn't change the duration of the query.